# What is the correct way of making multiple api calls in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-resource

Is this the only way of using $resource for multiple calls in angularjs

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});

User.get({userId:123}, function(user) {
  user.abc = true;
});
```

or we can do something like this-

```
mainApp.factory('service', [ '$resource',
function($resource) {
    var data = $resource('user', {

    }, {
        signUp : {
            url : '/api/signup',
            method : "POST"
        },
        message : {
            url : '/api/messages',
            params : {id : "@id"},
            method : "GET"
        },
    });
    return data;
}]);
```

and in controller

```
mainApp.controller('userController', ['$scope', 'service',
function($scope, service) {

    $scope.messages = function() {
            service.message({id: id}, function(userData) {
            console.log(userData);
        }
    }

    $scope.messages();
}]);
```

**or is there some more better way of doing this...?**

Comment: I don't see multiple calls in either of these examples?

Comment: I mean different calls instantiating same $resource rather than declaring different one

Comment: [the official angular documentation] for `$resource` has a very good example of a resource which is used to make a `GET`, `QUERY`, and `SAVE` in one instance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something like this:

```
mainApp.factory('service', [ '$resource',
function($resource) {
    var data = $resource('/api/:path', {
        path: '@path'
    }, {
        signUp : {
            params : {path: 'signup'},
            method : "POST"
        },
        message : {
            params : {path: 'messages'},
            method : "GET"
        },
    });
    return data;
}]);
```

Comment: And how to call service.message providing api path ?